# javascript:void(0) call to function

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

First time posting here, hope someone will help me find out the solution to a problem im facing!
Im trying to create a button in wordpress that would call an ajax function, i used an example from an existing one, but even if i change the class it still calls to the other function. Any suggestions on how to create a href to my new function while using javascript:void(0)?
Thanks in advance!

Attaching the working button:

```
<a data-toggle="tooltip" href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn-undo-approve-job-applied btn-action-icon approve" data-applicant_id="<?php echo esc_attr($post->ID); ?>" data-nonce="<?php echo esc_attr(wp_create_nonce( 'wp-job-board-pro-undo-approve-applied-nonce' )); ?>" title="<?php esc_html_e('Undo Approved', 'superio'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it all depends on your CSS framework but usually you'd want to use
`<button></button>` instead of anchor tags for creating buttons.

Nonetheless, `href` does not call functions, it just points to an address. In this case `javascript:void(0)` just tells `href` to do nothing.

Unless you have some crazy jQuery in there, changing the class should only change what the link/button looks like. That's what `class` is meant for anyway (imo).

I assume your AJAX call is in a javascript function somewhere. If you know what it's called you should be able to get your button or link to call it:

`<button onclick="myAjaxFunction()">Do It</button>`

I'm not too familiar with Bootstrap, but as Javascript and HTML goes, this is basically how it works.

Comment: Just tried out the onlick, but it's still calling the other function. I'm using a template of wordpress job application plugin so im not entirely sure on how the functions are build :/

Comment: Sounds like jQuery shenanigans. I would suggest adding a separate/empty/blank button (keep the old one but comment it out). Then first - try to get your new button to call the AJAX function. When that works, add all the bits to it until you get the desired look. When something goes wrong, just go one step back.

Comment: Found the js file with all declared onclick functions, at least something... Adding a new class doesnt really change anything, now the button doesnt even load :/

Comment: Bootstrap is.. magical. It does a lot of things behind the scenes and is generally impossible to debug. You're not really meant to dig around those files.

Edit: As a last resort, may I suggest not messing with that button. Create your own and debug from there.